# Задача с подкатегориями

Tags: mysql

Имеется набросок структуры и дампа базы данных MySQL:
http://pastebin.com/HiTP6bwN

Каким удобным образом возможно добавить к подкатегориям (сategory_info) еще подкатегории, не стараясь создавать при этом дополнительные таблицы?
Конкретно таблица для комнат в чате. Он должен иметь такой вид:

**getRoomList >**

```
Комната1
Комната2
Папка1
Комната3
```

**getRoomList 'Папка1'**

```
Комната1
Папка1
Комната3
```

**getRoomList 'Папка1'**

```
Комната1
Комната2
Комната3
```

Работаю с Java.

Comment: Ввести поле parent, в которое будет заноситься id категории-родителя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все деревья делаются из досок, а настоящие деревья не делаются, ибо слишком геморройно на уровне запросов, а геморрой на уровне скриптов быстро проходит, благо наработок как грязи.

То есть из обычных adjacent отношений делается дерево

```
id pid name
```

id - родитель
pid - потомок (parent id)
name - ну, какая-то полезная инфа, таких полей может быть сколько хочешь.

По ссылке в pid берется id, по pid в его строке берется id, по pid в его строке берется id, и поехали.

Comment: Можете обогатить свой ответ примерным кодом (структурой mysql и пример вывода на php)? Я не очень опытен во всем этом.

Comment: @Sergey_21
Тогда экспериментируйте. Это же замечательно. Начните, например, с ручки и листочка бумаги.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь:). Использую id,name,parent. Это идеально.

Comment: Структура показана, а процедуры - рекурсия. Которой нет в MySql и которая, соответственно, реализуется в скрипте.